# One of the partial html not loading in ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Previously I used ng-route (was working fine) but now I need ui-routing. Since I am not familiar much with AngularJs and not at all with `ui-router` I just did a simple config :-

```
    myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/award_config");
        $stateProvider.state("landing", {
            templateUrl : "screens/landing/landingTemplate.html",
            url: "/landing",
            controller : "landingController"
        }).state("csr_view_sub", {
            templateUrl : "screens/csr/home/csr_viewSubscriberTemplate.html",
            url: "/csr_view",
            controller : "csrController"
        }).state("pm_view_report", {
            templateUrl : "screens/manager/reports/pm_viewReportsTemplate.html",
            url: "/view_report",
            controller : "pm_viewReportsController"
        }).state("award_config", {
            templateUrl : "screens/manager/award_config/award_ConfigTemplate.html",
            url: "/award_config",
            controller : "awardConfigController"
        }).state("create_user", {
            templateUrl : "screens/manager/user/createUser.html",
            url: "/create_user",
            controller : "createUserController",
        }).state("groups", {
            templateUrl : "screens/manager/groups/group.html",
            url: "/groups",
            controller : "groupController"
        });
    });
```

Surprisingly, all the other partials are loading fine except `/create_user`.
If it helps I got errors of `transition superseeded` `transition aborted` and 2 more every time I reloaded `/create_user`. I am not getting that after upgrading version of ui-router, but functionally, still the ui-view is blank for `/create_user`.

The error:-

```
    angular.js:14800 Error: transition superseded
        at $StateProvider.$get (angular-ui-router.js:2866)
        at Object.invoke (angular.js:5106)
        at angular.js:4893
        at getService (angular.js:5047)
        at injectionArgs (angular.js:5072)
        at Object.invoke (angular.js:5098)
        at angular.js:8267
        at forEach (angular.js:408)
        at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:8265)
        at Object.invoke (angular.js:5106) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"
    (anonymous) @ angular.js:14800
    (anonymous) @ angular.js:11218
    processChecks @ angular.js:17199
    $digest @ angular.js:18352
    $apply @ angular.js:18649
    bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1958
    invoke @ angular.js:5106
    doBootstrap @ angular.js:1956
    bootstrap @ angular.js:1976
    angularInit @ angular.js:1861
    (anonymous) @ angular.js:34354
    fire @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3232
    fireWith @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3362
    ready @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3582
    completed @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3617
    angular.js:14800 Error: transition prevented
        at $StateProvider.$get (angular-ui-router.js:2867)
        at Object.invoke (angular.js:5106)
        at angular.js:4893
        at getService (angular.js:5047)
        at injectionArgs (angular.js:5072)
        at Object.invoke (angular.js:5098)
        at angular.js:8267
        at forEach (angular.js:408)
        at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:8265)
        at Object.invoke (angular.js:5106) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"
    (anonymous) @ angular.js:14800
    (anonymous) @ angular.js:11218
    processChecks @ angular.js:17199
    $digest @ angular.js:18352
    $apply @ angular.js:18649
    bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1958
    invoke @ angular.js:5106
    doBootstrap @ angular.js:1956
    bootstrap @ angular.js:1976
    angularInit @ angular.js:1861
    (anonymous) @ angular.js:34354
    fire @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3232
    fireWith @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3362
    ready @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3582
    completed @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3617
    angular.js:14800 Error: transition aborted
        at $StateProvider.$get (angular-ui-router.js:2868)
        at Object.invoke (angular.js:5106)
        at angular.js:4893
        at getService (angular.js:5047)
        at injectionArgs (angular.js:5072)
        at Object.invoke (angular.js:5098)
        at angular.js:8267
        at forEach (angular.js:408)
        at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:8265)
        at Object.invoke (angular.js:5106) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"
    (anonymous) @ angular.js:14800
    (anonymous) @ angular.js:11218
    processChecks @ angular.js:17199
    $digest @ angular.js:18352
    $apply @ angular.js:18649
    bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1958
    invoke @ angular.js:5106
    doBootstrap @ angular.js:1956
    bootstrap @ angular.js:1976
    angularInit @ angular.js:1861
    (anonymous) @ angular.js:34354
    fire @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3232
    fireWith @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3362
    ready @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3582
    completed @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3617
    angular.js:14800 Error: transition failed
        at $StateProvider.$get (angular-ui-router.js:2869)
        at Object.invoke (angular.js:5106)
        at angular.js:4893
        at getService (angular.js:5047)
        at injectionArgs (angular.js:5072)
        at Object.invoke (angular.js:5098)
        at angular.js:8267
        at forEach (angular.js:408)
        at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:8265)
        at Object.invoke (angular.js:5106) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"
    (anonymous) @ angular.js:14800
    (anonymous) @ angular.js:11218
    processChecks @ angular.js:17199
    $digest @ angular.js:18352
    $apply @ angular.js:18649
    bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1958
    invoke @ angular.js:5106
    doBootstrap @ angular.js:1956
    bootstrap @ angular.js:1976
    angularInit @ angular.js:1861
    (anonymous) @ angular.js:34354
    fire @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3232
    fireWith @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3362
    ready @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3582
    completed @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3617
```

Comment: what versions of angularjs and ui.router are you using?

Comment: The transition errors are encountered when there is something which prevents the transition from happening. Please look at your console, it should have the stacktrace/reason for the error.

Comment: You should post your browser console errors. With the information you provide, I doubt anybody is able to help.

Comment: @EduardoYáñezParareda My bad, but I mentioned that the errors went away after I upgraded ui-router version, I will change back and post the errors, please bear